# Wildcard domains (not sub domains) pointing to dedicated IP - /home/user/public_html/landing/

Tags: .htaccess, dns, wildcard, virtualhost, named

I'm looking for a solution to park unlimited domains without having to first having to define them (named.conf).

I want to give clients my nameservers to point their domains at, and have them land on a certain directory on my server. For example /home/user/public_html/landing/index.php

The closest site I can think of, that does similar is sedoparking.com

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Is `bind` a requirement? There may be other nameservers better suited. Also, since this is not really a programming question at its core, it is offtopic here.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @PatrickMevzek. No Bind isn't a requirement. Apologises if in the wrong section. How about if I ask how to create a PHP landing page for unlimited (wildcard) domain names? :)

Comment: For your question, see for example https://serverfault.com/a/397011/396475   You can ask about PHP too, that will be ontopic here indeed... if you show some code as the idea is to help debug problems with you on your code, not writing the code in your place.